# Is there any open source of chat room by react native?

Tags: react-native

Now,i want to create a project with react native which is a real chat room.
  Is there any open source project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [Gifted Messenger](https://github.com/FaridSafi/react-native-gifted-messenger) by [FaridSafi](https://github.com/FaridSafi). I haven't used it myself, but it looks pretty complete.